# bootstrap3 - how to change background color when in collapsed mode

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a bootstrap3 navbar with a transparent background - bootply is at http://www.bootply.com/XZ2f721AZD

Trouble is, I need a solid background color (#821726) on the drop down when the menu is collapsed.

I have a white background on dropdowns when the menu is enlarged, but can't work out what I have to change to get the background to only appear on the navbar dropdown in the "hamburger" view (still want the navbar itself to be transparent).

Thanks for any thoughts.

Comment: Your snippet isn't working well !

Comment: Can you add some code please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add a new class to your stylesheet:

```
.navbar-collapse.collapse.in
{
     background-color: #821726; // your color
}
```

Comment: Thank you this one worked perfectly for me! I did not try the other answer by Roman because on first look I thought it would make the whole navbar"non transparent", wher I was only lookin gforthe dropdowns. This worked just great, and I really do appreciate both of you!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you apply the css styles to all screen resolutions.

In this case the best way is to use media queries, so you can use certain css rules on certain screen resolutions or different devices.

In your case you could just add a media query rule at the very bottom of your css, which will change the background of your navbar when the navbar collapses. It collapses at 768px width:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
.navbar-inverse {
    background-color: #821726;
   }
}
```

Hope it helps.